# Automate jenkins slave node cleanup

Tags: automation, jenkins

**So here is the scenario:**
Currently to cleanup space on Jenkins slave we have a job(a jenkins job itself) scheduled to run every day to do the cleanup. But many a times disk get full between scheduled runs then we have run it manually.

**This is what I am looking for:**
Along with a schedule based cleanup I would like to have a demand based cleanup. Whenever a node disk get higher than say 70% that node should be taken offline, cleaned up and then put back online. All this should be automated. Is this possible?

I am a newbie to Jenkins so I can just speculate: Can we configure Jenkins to monitor its own slaves and trigger something(script etc) when a condition is met?

Thanks!

EDIT: I would not like to use extra softwares like nagios etc. to do the monitoring. What I am looking for is whether slaves themselves can say to master "we are unhealthy, save us!" or master can monitor slaves and do something when they are not healthy. Basically I want to know whether Jenkins has **self-healing** capability or I need to depend on a third party tool?

Comment: You should probably considering using traditional monitoring (Nagios, Monit, etc.) plus traditional configuration management (Chef, Puppet, Ansible, SaltStack, CFEngine, etc.) instead of using Jenkins as pseudo-monitoring and pseudo-configuration-management.

Comment: @jayhendren I understand what the use cases of jenkins,ansible,nagios are. My question is not exactly about configuration management. Kindly check my EDIT.